# How to determine membership relation from word2vec embedding

Tags: natural-language, word2vec, word-embeddings

Assume I have a trained `word2vec` embedding, given two words, it's easy to determine the similarity between the two words. However how do I know one word "belong to" another word's category?

For example, I have  the embeddings of "apple", "city", "fruit". Definitely "apple" should belong to "fruit" category, **but not in reverse**. "city" and "fruit" does not belong to each other. Now that I got two embedding vectors from unknown words: ${\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$, **how do I determine the degree that ${\bf u}$ belongs to ${\bf v}$?**

Alternatively, is there a different word embedding model/algorithm that can support this kind of inference?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible in a easy way, because word2vec can learn from context but even in a similar context, it can't develop a dependency relation.

For that kind of belong relation you should get use of wordnet (i.e).

https://wordnet.princeton.edu/ take a look, maybe it is you case.